# I need the build.ninja file to build chromium and it isn't generated

Tags: chromium, ninja

I was trying to build chromium, but when I run `autoninja -C out/Default chrome`, it says this:

`ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.`

It's in spanish, but it basically says that the system can't find the specified file.

That's right, it isn't a build.ninja file. But I don't know how to generate it.

Anything to make?

Edit, things I already tried:

- Use gn gen out/Default, it throws an error.
- Use it from Windows Terminal (CMD and PS) and from VS, same result for three ways.
- Trying use VS 19 instead of 22, same result.
- Edit manually \build\config\win\visual_studio_version.gni

Additional info:

- I have Windows 11 and I use Visual Studio 2022, along with Visual Studio Code, I installed 2019 to try on if works with it, but not. :( If anything more is requiered, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the build files before using ninja. Execute the following command:

```
gn gen out/Default
```

Then execute the `autoninja` command:

```
autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

Comment: I already make that, but it throws me `ERROR at //build/config/win/visual_studio_version.gni:27:7: Script returned non-zero exit code.`. EDIT: The entire output of the command is this: [https://imgur.com/a/3fwWMsY](https://imgur.com/a/3fwWMsY)

Comment: Can you run that from Visual Studio command prompt? It will set all the required env. variables required for that process. Also make sure a supported version of Visual Studio is being used

Comment: Ok, I tried to run `gn gen out/Default` from the Developer PowerShell on VS and it's the same result. I am using the latest Visual Studio (2022), that says it's compatible, so theorically any problem with that. Also, the PATH is set on depot_tools, vs2022_install is on C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community, and DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN is set on 0.

Comment: Not sure if VS 2022 is compatible but am using 2019. Try switching to 2019 if it doesn't work. Before doing so, try `gn clean out\Default`. As you are using Windows, try using ``\`` instead of `/` in path too which might be causing that issue

Comment: Using 2019 it's same result. [https://imgur.com/a/nGW7khU](https://imgur.com/a/nGW7khU) I also tried it with \

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the configuration of either gn or depot_tools. I don't see that problem here

Comment: I think it's my PC or Windows, because, even using a videotutorial to view the process (to make sure I am not doing something wrong), it doesn't work. I will try use Linux instead of Windows, or use my desktop computer, instead of my laptop.